# Select option removed on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I want to delete the option with value =0  when the user dropDownList..

**Select:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

    <form:select id="CONTEXTE" path="CONTEXTE" onclick="go()" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1" >
        <form:option value="0">Sélectionner une option</form:option>
        <form:options items="${cntxt}" itemLabel="CONTEXTE_CD" itemValue="id"/>
    </form:select>
```

**Function:**

```
<script>
    function go(){
        $(".select2_single option[value='0']").remove();        
    }
</script>
```

Where am going wrong ?

Thanks for any advices..

Comment: "select" has no onClick method. is onChange satisfying?

Comment: That's not standard HTML, I would add a tag of what you are using (Spring).

Comment: I havent seen html code formated in the way you have it, but i just changed `<form:select>` and `<form:option>` to `<select>` and `<option>` and it worked fine for me.  @AliSheikhpour im able to use onClick on a select field.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour onChange method is working.. but i dont want the display the option with value 0 when dropdownlist ..

Comment: Ok. Wrap **select** element with a div or span and define an "onClick" on  the wrapper.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek post updated

Comment: @JoseRodrigues can u share ur code because onclick method is not working for me

Comment: @AliSheikhpour i wraped select with a div and define onClick methode on it..it didnt work

Comment: @FuSsA you want change <form:select> and <form:option> to <select> and <option> ,and fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select

```
<div onclick="disbtn();">
<form:select id="CONTEXTE" path="CONTEXTE"   class="select" tabindex="-1" >
<form:option id="aa" value="0">Sélectionner une option</form:option>
<form:options items="${cntxt}" itemLabel="CONTEXTE_CD" itemValue="id"/>
</form:select>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>
    function disbtn() {         
        $('#aa').remove();     
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not failiar with the spring framework and am not exactly sure if it effects how jquery selectors work but have you tried using pure javascript.

change html

```
onclick="go(this)"
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function go(element){
  if(element.options[0].value==0){
       element.remove(0);
  };  
}
</script>
```